# Replace a string pattern by a sequence using sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

I want to replace a string in a text file with a sequence of numbers such as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 preferably using sed.

Here is what I have tried (without the search string) and seems to work:

```bsh
for i in {1..5};do echo $(seq 1 $i); done
```

The output:

```bsh
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

However, when I try this:

```bsh
for i in {1..5};do sed -i "s/abc/$(seq 1 $i)/g" test; done
```

I get the following error:

```bsh
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

I have tried enclosing the replacement string in brackets as well, but it does not seem to work.

The first loop

```bsh
for i in {1..5}
```

will be replaced by a glob for filenames within which I want to replace some parameters.

Comment: can u share the content of text file...

Comment: The test text file I am using is just the letters abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL; DR:**

There can be some ways to work around that, I think the cleanest for your sample case is:

```bash
for i in {1..5};do sed -i "s/abc/$(seq -s ' ' 1 $i)/g" test; done
```

That is: we request `seq` to use one single space to separate each number.

**Explanation:**

The reason why you got those errors is because the output from:

```
seq 1 5
```

is not:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

but rather:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And since you enclosed the `$(seq 1 $i)` [Command Substitution](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) within double-quotes, the usual [Word Splitting](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) is not performed, hence all the newlines (except the last) output by the `seq` utility are left as is.

Therefore the actual `sed` command has become:

```
sed -i "s/abc/1
2
3
4
5
/g" test
```

which is not accepted because, as far as `sed` is concerned, you provided it with a `s/abc/1` command, i.e. lacking the required final `/`.

An `echo $(seq 1 5)` does print `1 2 3 4 5` because the `$(seq 1 5)` is not within double-quotes, therefore Word Splitting occurs as per shell's default behavior.

We might indeed fix your sample case also as in:

```bash
for i in {1..5};do sed -i "s/abc/$(echo $(seq 1 $i))/g" test; done
```

that is, by doing a Command Substitution (your original `seq 1 $i`) *inside* another Command Substitution (the `echo` one).

This works even within the double-quotes because the `$(echo ...)` Command Substitution is run in a *subshell* which is *not* in the "I-am-inside-a-double-quote" state, so Word Splitting on the output from `seq` *will* be performed there.

Comment: Instead of `echo $(seq 1 $i)` you could use `seq -s' ' 1 $i`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to a temporary file, then move the temporary file over the original one. Also, you *may* have meant to operate on one line at a time, in which case you should drop the `g`:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    sed -e "s/abc/$(seq 1 $i)/" test > test.tmp
    mv test.tmp test
done
```

Comment: This expression also gives the same error. I think the problem here is that bash is probably unable to print the entire sequence out at once.
It's confusing because the format works with echo command but not with sed.